# MVVM Cross - OnNavigatedTo not firing

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm now retro-fitting MVVM Cross to an existing WinRT/WP8 app. I've got IoC and Navigation working, but I can't get the LayoutAwarePage.OnNavigatedTo event to fire, to instantiate the related ViewModel

I've set the ViewModel property in the HomeView, that is detected and HomeView loads, but then the base OnNavigatedTo event doesn't fire to load up HomeViewModel

any pointers on what to go through to find out what's wrong?

thanks

Toby

Answer (score 2):

figured it out half-way through writing when checking the names - in my legacy app, I'd already overriden OnNavigatedTo, so the one in LayoutAwarePage that then calls the Mvx code to load the ViewModel was ignored ...dolt

Comment: Well done Toby - this is actually a common problem with the MS `LayoutAwarePage` - it overrides both `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` (or is it `OnNavigatingFrom`?) - but then never calls the `base` implementations :( There's a step about it in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/an-quick-start-on-creating-mvvmcross.html - but there are a lot of steps, so it's easy to lose it...